# InnoSetup: How to pass a two dimensional string array to a function

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Innosetup is killing me. I am getting a RUNTIME 'Type Mismatch' error, where it is, to me, quite unexpected. I am using Inno-setup 5.5.3 (u) 
(where the 'u' means the unicode version)

I am attempting to pass a two dimensional array into a method.

Here is my complete example.

```
[Setup]
AppName=EmptyProgram
AppVerName=EmptyProgram 1
UsePreviousAppDir=false
DefaultDirName={pf}\EmptyProgram
Uninstallable=false
OutputBaseFilename=HelloWorld
PrivilegesRequired=none

[Messages]
SetupAppTitle=My Title

[Code]
var
    langMap : array[0..3] of array[0..1] of String;


function getMapVal(map : array of array[0..1] of String; key: String ) : String;
begin
    Result:='not testing the body of the method';
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    MsgBox('Hello world.', mbInformation, MB_OK);

    getMapVal(langMap, 'hello');    // this line here fails with type mismatch! Why?

    Result := FALSE;
end;
```

This example would run, but for the invokation of the method:

getMapVal(langMap, 'hello');

It compiles, and therefore is happy with the declaration. But on invokation, mismatch error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're not making a hash map, but a pure key value list. There's currently no way to make a real generics hash map in InnoSetup at this time. Anyway, your current code needs a complete refactor. I'd rather write it this way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
type
  TKey = string;
  TValue = string;
  TKeyValue = record
    Key: TKey;
    Value: TValue;
  end;
  TKeyValueList = array of TKeyValue;

function TryGetValue(const KeyValueList: TKeyValueList; const Key: TKey; 
  var Value: TValue): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(KeyValueList) - 1 do
    if KeyValueList[I].Key = Key then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Value := KeyValueList[I].Value;
      Exit;
    end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var 
  I: Integer;
  Value: TValue;
  KeyValueList: TKeyValueList;
begin
  SetArrayLength(KeyValueList, 3);
  for I := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    KeyValueList[I].Key := 'Key' + IntToStr(I);
    KeyValueList[I].Value := 'Value' + IntToStr(I);
  end;

  if TryGetValue(KeyValueList, 'Key2', Value) then
    MsgBox('Value: ' + Value, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: thanks for that interesting example. One thing I notice now, since i'd like to be able to simplify the 'insertion' of elements (not just the getting), is there seems to be no 'pass by referennce' ?? Is that so? i.e., it is impossible to move the 'insertion' code into a procedure, do the insertion inside that method (and expect the values to be still there once the procedure has completed) ?

Comment: That's an example of how you should implement a key value list of strings. In other words, your code, but refactored. What you're asking is a topic for another question since I don't know what you mean precisely.

Comment: No, sorry, never mind. While I was having troubles with my own code, in (re)testing yours (correctly this time) I discover I made a mistake. I have no trouble of the sort I mentioned in the previous comment. Thanks again for your help.